# Make a search form where the user doesnt have to enter every field

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm working on making a form to connect to a database.  It works good so far.  It displays information.  However I want to include more then one field.
Like if I were only to enter "Oakland" in the "Location" form.
I think the isset field is the part I'm getting stuck at.  I tried include '&!' or '||' to no effect.  Or maybe its my html. I tried to include some code in the "isset" and it came up a "No data retrieved from server" error came up on browser.  Because I only entered one field. I want to do it based on where the user enters information. BTW I do have a include in it to include the other files. Its just a snippet. It just I think that this is where my errors at.
 Here is my html code. If you guys could help me figure out how to do this.

```
echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "<title>Your Title Here</title>";
echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />";
echo "</head>";
echo "<body onLoad=\"self.focus();document.searchform.search.focus()\">";
echo "<center>";
echo "<br /><form name=\"searchform\" method=\"GET\" action=\"search.php\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"search\" size=\"20\" TABINDEX=\"1\" />";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"Institution\" size=\"20\" TABINDEX=\"1\" />";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"Location\" size=\"20\" TABINDEX=\"1\" />";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"ProjectNotes\" size=\"20\" TABINDEX=\"1\" />";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"TotalFunding\" size=\"20\" TABINDEX=\"1\" />";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"ActiveYear\" size=\"20\" TABINDEX=\"1\" />";
echo " <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Search\" />";
echo "</form>";
//search variable = data in search box or url
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = $_GET['search'];
    Investigator($search);
}
```

Investigator function

```
function Investigator($search)
{

    $search = trim($search);
    $search = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $search);

//seperate multiple keywords into array space delimited
    $keywords = explode(" ", $search);

//Clean empty arrays so they don't get every row as result
    $keywords = array_diff($keywords, array(
        ""
    ));

//Set the MySQL query
    if ($search == NULL or $search == '%') {
    } else {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($keywords); $i++) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM Studies " . "WHERE Investigator LIKE '%$keywords[$i]%'" . " OR      Location LIKE '%$keywords[$i]%'" . " OR TotalFundingAmount LIKE '%$keywords[$i]%'" . " OR  Institution LIKE    '%$keywords[$i]%'" . " ORDER BY Location";
        }

        //Store the results in a variable or die if query fails
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    if ($search == NULL or $search == '%') {
    } else {
        //Count the rows retrived
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo $count;
    }

//If search variable is null do nothing, else print it.
    if ($search == NULL) {
    } else {
        echo "You searched for <b><FONT COLOR=\"blue\">";
        foreach ($keywords as $value) {
            print "$value ";
        }
        echo "</font></b>";
    }
    echo "<p> </p><br />";
    echo "</center>";

//If users doesn't enter anything into search box tell them to.
    if ($search == NULL) {
        echo "<center><b><FONT COLOR=\"red\">Please enter a search parameter to continue.</font></b><br /></center>";
    } elseif ($search == '%') {
        echo "<center><b><FONT COLOR=\"red\">Please enter a search parameter to continue.</font></b><br /></center>";
        //If no results are returned print it
    } elseif ($count <= 0) {
        echo "<center><b><FONT COLOR=\"red\">Your query returned no results from the database.</font></b><br /></center>";
        //ELSE print the data in a table
    } else {
        //Table header
        echo "<center>";
        echo "</center>";

        //Colors for alternation of row color on results table
        $color1 = "#d5d5d5";
        $color2 = "#e5e5e5";
        //While there are rows, print it.
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            //Row color alternates for each row
            $row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2;
            //table background color = row_color variable
            echo "<center><table bgcolor=" . $row_color . ">";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Investigator'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TotalFundingAmount'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Institution'] . "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table></center>";
            $row_count++;
            //end while
        }
        //end if
    }

    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
    if ($search == NULL or $search == '%') {
    } else {
        //clear memory
        mysql_free_result($result);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you need to be able to search for multiple fields at once as well?

Comment: You shouldn't wrap all your HTML in echos. It would make your HTML more readable and easier to decode. And I see nothing wrong in this code, you should include your complete source, especially the part with `No data retrieved from server`.

Comment: Yea Jack I do need to search for multiple fields as well.

Comment: Can you post your `Investigator()` function please.

Comment: Also, like @MathieuImbert said, you should not wrap your HTML in echos. You can go in and out of PHP as will.

Comment: You are not using values sent via these form fields: `Institution`, `Location`, `ProjectNotes`, `TotalFunding`, `ActiveYear`.

Answer (score 0):

isset() only checks to see if a variable is defined.  empty() may be what you want to use in this case, because it will specifically check to see if the form input is empty.

Using this you can then construct a query which will be executed--in fact, it might eliminate the need for a separate function.  I haven't looked too much at the function code you posted.  But it would go something like this:

Say you have input fields x, y, and z.  You want to be able to run a query that returns all the information matching any of these fields that are filled out.  The script, then, would run the same pattern of code for each input, with $datax being the data from the form.

```
if (empty($datax) == false) //If the data is NOT empty...
    {
    $stringx = "column = {$datax}"; //Assign a chunk of a mySQL query requesting matching info to a string.
    }
else //If the data IS empty...
    {
    $stringx = "1"; //Create the same variable, but make it 1.  You'll see why.
    }
//Repeat the above for $datay and $stringy, $dataz and $stringz, etc.  Next is another if to make sure the entire form isn't left blank.
if (empty($datax) == true && empty($datay) == true && empty($dataz) == true)
    {
    //Code to return an "Empty form!" error
    }
else
    {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE " . $stringx . " AND " . $stringy . " AND " . $stringz;
    //Continue to run query
    }
```

What this does is construct a query from the data results.  If, for example, a user searches for USA, a blank field, and industrial, (with fields being location, weather, and type respectively--again, all just an example) the query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE location = 'USA' AND 1 AND type = 'industrial'
```

Any fields left blank result in an AND 1 statement inserted, not affecting the query.  Hope that clears things up a little, let me know if I can make further edits to help.

Comment: Um I'm kinda new.  Could you break it down a little bit simpler.  Thanks

Comment: Was this at all helpful, or...?